# How can I create different menus for home and for the other pages?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, menu

I need to create different menus. One menu for Home page and another menu for other pages and posts. Below is the code for my Home page menu:

```
<div class="main-menu-wrapper hidden-xs clearfix">
  <div class="main-menu">

    <?php wp_nav_menu( apply_filters( 'nominee_primary_wp_nav_men', array(
        'container'      => false,
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'items_wrap'     => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s nav navbar-nav navbar-right">%3$s</ul>',
        'walker'         => new Nominee_Navwalker(),
        'fallback_cb'    => 'Nominee_Navwalker::fallback'
        ))); 
     ?>

  </div> <!-- /navbar-collapse -->
</div>
```

This is a part of code that creates me the menu I needed. Do I just have to create two menus, one called **Menu1(for Home Page)** and the other called **Menu2 (for other pages)**. Now I need to control if a user is in Home Page then I will call Menu1, if a user is not in home ( so it's the page or a post) I will call Menu2.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: use can used `is_home()` or `is_front_page()` function of wordpress: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/

Comment: I don't know how I can show Menu1 or Menu2. I have just tried is_home or is_front_page() but I don't show any menu.

Comment: @MinalChauhan do you know some function that it let me to understand if the menu is primary or not?^

Comment: Also you can easy make a secondary menu, and with css choose which one use.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin. it will give you menu manager option in  edit pages/post. so you can select different menus for different pages/posts
https://wordpress.org/plugins/different-menu-in-different-pages/screenshots/

Comment: I have just used this but If I create more then 5 posts it doesn't work anymore because say me that I have reached a limit

Comment: In free version you can only use it for 5 posts/pages if you want to use it for no limit then you have to purchase the premium plugin.